# Is it possible to use '+' selector with :host on Angular 6?

Tags: angular, sass, angular6

I'm trying to add a 2rem margin between equal components using the plus (+) css selector inside own decorator but it's not working.

Is there any way to encapsulate this behavior inside component?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bx-button',
  template: `
    <button class="bx--btn bx--btn--{{type}} {{className}}" type="button"
       [disabled]="disabled" [ngClass]="{'bx--btn--sm' : small}">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
     </button>
   `,
   styles: [`
     :host + :host {
       margin-left: 2rem
     }
   `]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pretty way for this. There are four ways I can think of

1. You can make a global styles .scss and include this in your build. This won't have any encapsulation.

   ```
   bx-button + bx-button {
     margin-left: 2rem;
   }
   ```
2. You can set the encapsulation to None of the component

   ```
   @Component({
     selector: 'bx-button',
     template: `
       <button class="bx--btn bx--btn--{{type}} {{className}}" type="button"
          [disabled]="disabled" [ngClass]="{'bx--btn--sm' : small}">
         <ng-content></ng-content>
        </button>
      `,
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
      styles: [`
          bx-button + bx-button {
             margin-left: 2rem;
          }
      `]
   })
   ```
3. You can use the deprecated `::ng-deep` selector

   ```
   @Component({
     selector: 'bx-button',
     template: `
       <button class="bx--btn bx--btn--{{type}} {{className}}" type="button"
          [disabled]="disabled" [ngClass]="{'bx--btn--sm' : small}">
         <ng-content></ng-content>
        </button>
      `,
      styles: [`
          ::ng-deep bx-button + bx-button {
             margin-left: 2rem;
          }
      `]
   })
   ```
4. You handle it in the host component where it uses the `bx-button`

Comment: I've tried the encapsulation none as on second item and it didn't work. Once I'm creating an external library I think the best solution would be the first one but I'm not sure how to externalize a scss file on an angular library. I'll do some research now. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @ViníciusPavin you can just add a `scss` file to the `styles` array inside the `angular.json`. About the encapsulation, I didn't test it, but I guess it also needs the `::ng-deep` selector